tn3 gallery within web page called by API into WordPress site not working
I am creating a custom WordPress plugin where a API call is made to display a web page in the WordPress site. The web page called by API has a image gallery made with tn3 gallery, which does not appear.
I have ensured jQuery file is being loaded before the tn3 script. This is my code snippet:
$url = "https://listings.heropm.com/RPL5/calls/loadListing.mvc?prid=TX0550L&layout=GET";

$response = wp_remote_get($url);
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
echo "<div id = 'hero'>" . $body . "</div>";

